# Performance of reflection method call vs delegate call

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, delegates

My goal is to write a *weakly typed* `TryParse` method that is going support basically all the available struct types (int, long, float...)

```
public static bool TryParse(Type type, string s, out object obj)
```

The implementation is going to invoke the `TryParse` method of the provided `type` argument (if type is `int`, `int.TryPase` will be invoked and the out value is going to be returned as object).

I've implemented it via reflection, but there is a major performance penalty (as I expected)

The Reflection Implementation:

```
public static class ParserHelper
{
    public delegate bool TryParseDl(string str, out object obj);

    private static readonly HashSet<Type> ParsableStructs = new HashSet<Type>
    {
    typeof(int),
    typeof(uint),
    typeof(decimal),
    typeof(short),
    typeof(ushort),
    typeof(double),
    typeof(long),
    typeof(ulong),
    typeof(float),
    typeof(byte),
    typeof(sbyte)
    };

    public static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, TryParseDl> StructParsers;

    static ParserHelper()
    {
        StructParsers = new ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, TryParseDl>(CreateParsersForStructs());
    }

    /// Creates parsers for structs
            private static Dictionary<Type, TryParseDl> CreateParsersForStructs()
        {
            var parsers = new Dictionary<Type, TryParseDl>();
            foreach (var t in ParsableStructs)
            {
                parsers[t] = GetParserForStruct(t);
            }
            return parsers;
        }

    private static TryParseDl GetParserForStruct(Type targetType)
        {
            var methodInfo = targetType.GetMethod(
                "TryParse",
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
                Type.DefaultBinder,
                new[] { typeof(string), targetType.MakeByRefType() },
                null);

            return (string str, out object obj) =>
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                    {
                        obj = targetType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(targetType) : null;
                        return true;
                    }
                    var inputParameters = new object[] { str, null };
                    var tryParseResult = (bool)methodInfo.Invoke(null, inputParameters);
                    obj = inputParameters[1];
                    return tryParseResult;
                };
        }
}
```

And here is the performance test:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        string str = "100";     
        s.Start();
        for(int j = 0;j<100;j++)
        {
            int i;
            int.TryParse(str,out i);

        }
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
        s.Reset();
        s.Start();
        var parser = ParserHelper.StructParsers[typeof(int)];   
        for(int j = 0;j<100;j++)
        {                           
            object o;
            parser(str, out o);
        }

        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

The average result is that reflection invocation is a bout 200 times slower than direct invocation (on 100 reties). [Fiddle that demonstrates the reflection test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LcVqMy)

I tried to improve performance by using a cached delegates:

```
public static class StructParserExtensions
{
    public static bool IntToObjParse(string str, out object obj)
    {
        int i;
        var result = int.TryParse(str, out i);
        obj = result ? (object)i : null;
        return result;
    }

    public static bool LongToObjParse(string str, out object obj)
    {
        long i;
        var result = long.TryParse(str, out i);
        obj = result ? (object)i : null;
        return result;
    }

    //implementations for other types goes here

}


public static class ParserHelper
{
    public delegate bool TryParseDl(string str, out object obj);

    public static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, TryParseDl> StructParsers;

    static ParserHelper()
    {
        StructParsers = new ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, TryParseDl>(CreateParsersForStructs());
    }

    /// Creates parsers for structs
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Dictionary</returns>
    private static Dictionary<Type, TryParseDl> CreateParsersForStructs()
    {

        var parsers = new Dictionary<Type, TryParseDl>();
        parsers[typeof(int)] = StructParserExtensions.IntToObjParse;                      
        parsers[typeof(long)] = StructParserExtensions.LongToObjParse;           
        return parsers;
    }           
}
```

I assumed that using delegates will drastically improve the performance so it will be close to the direct invocation, but I was wrong it is still about 100 times slower (on 100 reties)
[Here is the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RYx0Zt)

**My questions are:**

1. While I saw multiple examples where converting reflection calls into delegate calls makes the difference, it doesn't do the job in this case. Why?
2. Is there any way to improve the performance in this case?

Comment: If you are comparing the performance of this code to other code it would be useful to have a reference to the other code. Its really hard to say "Why does this perform slower" when we don't know what the faster code is. There can be any number of reasons for the performance difference. I'm looking at your code and thinking "It uses reflection, of course its slower than the version not using reflection"..

Comment: I have links to both fiddles attached
delegates: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RYx0Zt
reflection: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LcVqMy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just testing 100 iterations. You're mostly testing one-time startup overhead. Increase the iteration count until each test takes 1 second. That way the overhead disappears in the noise.

Currently, your code runs for .5 milliseconds. That is far *in* the noise range. After fixing that I get:

```
00:00:00.9711365
00:00:01.0958751 //Slightly slower
```

This benchmark uses 1e7 iterations whereas the previous one used 1e2.
Also make sure to test in Release mode without debugger attached on the bitness that you care about.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply.Increasing the number of iterations to 1e7, did prove your point. Also looks like reflection invocation is about 10 times slower than a direct invocation. So I do see the difference now. The interesting point here is that if the expected number of iterations is relatively small than the difference between reflection call and delegate call is relatively negligible.

Comment: You can't conclude that because you are not measuring just the call styles but also the one-time overhead. Reflection might just have a high startup cost.; You can try running a single warmup iteration first. That takes away the one-time overhead and you can get away with fewer iterations.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
        private object Converter(object inVal, Type t)
    {
        return Convert.ChangeType(inVal, t);
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with trying out something and learning something in the processes ?

Comment: @Stralos: While it doesn't asnwer the first question it does seem to answer the second question of how to have a better performing version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

As it was stated before. With 100 iterations you are most probably measuring only the overhead.

I took the testing a little bit further.
I joined your codes into one and ran 450 iteration to get some statistical data.
I set it to parse 10 milion times (10^7)

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/65dhdX9t

Here is the result of few last iterations:
m-method, d-delegate, r-reflection
[image: Statistics]
To sum it up:
- Delegation is aprox. 1.195x slower against direct call
- Reflection is aprox. 6.105x slower against direct call

Hope it helps! It sure helped me to convince me to transfer from reflection to delegation.